# Проверить input на сотые

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть `input`, как сделать проверку, если `val` есть 0.333 показывать ошибку, а если 0.22 то все хорошо.

Делаю вот так ничего и не выходит.

```js
function validCurencyForNumber() {
  var curencyVal = $('#curency').val();
  curencyVal = parseFloat(curencyVal).toFixed(2);
  if (curencyVal) {
    showError('Введите верное значение');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="curency" regex="^[0-9]+([.]|[,])?[0-9]*([0-9]+)?$" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
```

Comment: прежде всего проверьте корректность вашего регулярного выражения, например на сайте https://regexr.com/. ваша регулярка пропускает любое количество цифр после точки.

Comment: окей, как тогда в регулярке прописать: что бы пропускало только 2 числа после комы, а если больше то выдавало ошибку

Comment: ^\d*[.,]?\d{0,2}$

Comment: Наверно не regex а pattern. `<input pattern=^\d*[.,]?\d{0,2}$` потому что pattern делает проверку. (Ну... если вы хотите встроеную в браузер проверку).